# Xcode 10, where are the UI elements?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, uistoryboard, xcode10

Have been out of Swift coding for almost a year, I'm back.

Download Xcode 10 beta. Have I lost my mind?  I've tried every trick I know, none of the UI elements show up in storyboard. Zero. The sidebar is empty.

Xcode 10:

[image: Xcode 10 Screenshot]

Xcode 9, no problem there they are, all my UI buttons, etc.

thanks, this is kind of surreal. :-)

Comment: Cmd-Shift-L should do it

Comment: Unbelievable, this is called usability and UX.

Comment: Same situation- hadn't been in Swift for a year. Came back and couldn't even find a button to drag into IB. Thought I had lost it all.

Comment: Apple's tools are g-g-garbage. They hate developers, clearly.

Answer (score 286, accepted):

Library content has moved from the bottom of the `Inspector` area to an overlay window, which can be moved and resized like `Spotlight` search. It dismisses once items are dragged, but holding the `Option` key before dragging will keep the library open for an additional drag.

The library can be opened via:

- a new toolbar button (image attached);
- the `View` > `Libraries` menu;
- or the <kbd>⇧⌘L</kbd> keyboard shortcut.

[image]

Comment: is there no way to restore it on the sidebar?

Comment: The option key... who knew!... is there any way to make that the regular action? Just when you think Xcode can't get worse, they produce a new release.

Comment: I don't see the "new toolbar button", is it still there - xcode11.2?

Comment: @KamenDobrev, yes, but in Xcode 11 it looks like a plus "+" button

Answer (score 18):

Don't scare about you don't find **Library, Snippet, Media.**

#### Find Library or Snippet

**Show Library**

```
view -> Libraries -> Show Library
```

[image]

[image]

**Open Library**

```
view -> Libraries -> Show Library + Keyboard(Alt Key)
```

Shortcut Show Library : **Command + Shift + L**

Shortcut Open Library : **Command + Shift + Alt + L**

*Note : This is only works when you are in storyboard or xib file, otherwise it will open snippet. Same shortcut will works for open snippet and show snippet*

#### Open/Show Snippet

Same shortcut will works, let me explain.

Just goto(select) `.swift` file or `viewcontrolelr.h` file or `viewcontroller.m` file and fire show library shortcut / open library shortcut it will show Snippet dialog.

#### Find Media

```
view -> Libraries -> Show Media
```

Shortcut Show Library : **Command + Shift + M**
Shortcut Open Library : **Command + Shift + Alt + M**

Answer (score 11):

With ***Xcode 11***, the icon has changed to **+** (a plus sign), while **cmd+shift+L** works as usual.

[image: xCode 11 Screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

for media library content you should use keyboard shortcut <kbd>⇧⌘M</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have just found that it is as per screenshot and it will be opened with given shortcut/hotkey. Simply by dragging UI components to your Storyboard.

***Command + Shift + L***

[image]

[image]