# Xcode 11, where are the UI elements?

Tags: ios, xcode

In XCode 9, we could access the UI Element from the below
[image]

In XCode 10, it changes to another location as below. That itself already confuse others, as stated in [Xcode 10, where are the UI elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51051532/3286489)
[image]

Now in XCode 11, it disappear again! I know I could access it from Menu View->Show-Library (Shift-Cmd-L), but where's the shortcut now?
[image]

Comment: Did you try to press "+" button, which is located at the same place as in XCode 10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways after you open a **Storyboard**.

1. Try + button
2. Try keyboard shortcut `Cmd` + `Shift` + `L`

[image]

Comment: Nice one. Didn't expect the `+` sign is now add UI Elements

Comment: This is my reaction too. I don't know why people downvoted this valid question.