# Where is the "add a UI control" option in Xcode 14.1?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, xib, xcode14

There used to be a section on the right side of xib file to select a UI control (e.g. button, checkbox, text area, etc) from menu, and add to xib file. But after upgrading to Xcode 14.1 the option is gone. I can't find it anywhere.

[image]

Previously it looked like this:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 10, where are the UI elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51051532/xcode-10-where-are-the-ui-elements)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a plus sign in the upper right corner. See screenshot:

[image]

Then this should pop up. You can drag and drop what you want onto the storyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just googled up, the thing is called "Object Library", and the command to open it is:

**Command + Shift + L**

Thanks Adrian for showing the button in screenshot!

Comment: Or from the Xcode menu bar: View -> Show Library.